# Array passed to each() is null

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to store some data to an array.
However, the public array I created becomes null inside the `each()`.
How to rectify ?

```
public $questions = array();

public function crawl(){
    $questions = array();
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://indiabusinessquiz.com/');
    $crawler->filter('p > strong')->each(function ($node) {       
      $ques = $node->text();
      echo $ques;
      var_dump($ques);
      array_push($questions, $ques);
    });
}
```

**Error:**
ErrorException in Crawler.php line 20:
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The anonymous function doesn't automatically get access to outside variables. You need to use the `use()` option to access outer variables. And it needs to be a reference so that modifications inside the function affect the original variable, not a copy.

```
$crawler->filter('p > strong')->each(function ($node) use (&$questions) {       
  $ques = $node->text();
  echo $ques;
  var_dump($ques);
  array_push($questions, $ques);
});
```

BTW, the `$questions` variable in the function is not the same as the `$questions` property of the class. You need to do:

```
$this->questions = $questions;
```

at the end of the function if you want it saved in the class property.

Comment: I did this but for some reason when I var_dump the $questions array it returns empty.

Comment: I needed to make it a reference, otherwise it's modifying a copy of the array.